# Was Haman so discourteous as to bother the king's sleep?

Tags: purim, megillat-esther, sleep, haman

There are 2 related parts to this question:

1) Haman is annoyed with Mordechai and discusses with Zeresh, his wife and his wise advisers what to do. In [Esther 5:14](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3305.htm), they tell him to make a tall tree, and in the **morning** tell the king about his plans.

2) [Chapter 6](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3306.htm) starts with the king having trouble sleeping. In Esther [6:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.6.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), we find that Haman came to the palace's outer court to tell the king about his plan to hang Mordechai.

**Question:**

We see that Haman didn't quite listen to his wife or his wise men to go in the morning and instead went at night. Was he so delirious about his plan that he forgoes the advise of his own wise men, and furthermore dares to disturb the king's nighttime rest?
(Granted, the king was awake, but Haman didn't know that, and seems that he wanted to awaken the king in the middle of the night).

Comment: also why does it say yahasu?

Comment: it is interesting to note that his wife and friends said let them make the gallow ,yahasu is plural ,yet at the end of the passuk it say haman made them himself,it seems like he liked the idea and completed the task by himself since he finished he can go the king and show him the gallows. while his wife and friends thought that it can be done tomorrow by others and its not so urgent ,I guess he felt it was urgent.

Comment: Maybe Haman wanted to camp out in the king's court to meet him at daybreak?

Comment: It says וְהָמָן בָּא לַחֲצַר בֵּית הַמֶּלֶךְ הַחִיצוֹנָה - he was in the outside courtyard - seems like he was waiting for the king to awaken.

Comment: @DannySchoemann - I had thought of that *diyyuk*. Even with that, it still seems that he didn't listen to his wife and advisors. Maybe he really was delirious with his hatred towards Mordechai. So much so that the embarrassment to kill him alone disappeared quite quickly.

Answer (score 3):

I think that re-reading the Megila may actually suggest that Hamman DID wait till morning to go to the king.
The king was unable to fall asleep and so they read to him the Book of Memories, but I think that between Pasuk [ג'](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.6.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [ד'](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.6.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) a few hours have passed and it was already the morning. The reasons I believe that this would seem the most reasonable answer are:

- There was a death penalty for whomever entered the palace uninvited. I find it hard to believe the even Hamman was that careless and stupid as to throw away all his hard work and not wait for another six hours.
- Achashverosh tells Hamman to "quickly" do as he said and take Mordechai. It dosen't seem likely that Achashverosh wanted Mordechai to be woken up in the middle of the night and taken on a parade that nobody is awake to see.

So I think that Hamman ***did*** listen to his wife, and that he only went to the king the next morning (and so there is a few hours gap between [6:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.6.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [6:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.6.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Comment: "death penalty for whomever entered the palace uninvited"??? That is an exageration.. it was for somebody who entered the throne room.

Comment: Was Hamman planning on yelling to the king from the courtroom? I have a strong feeling he was on his way to the throne room.

Comment: ...or he was on the way to put his name on the waiting list. But since he had the king's signet, I have a feeling that he had free access to the king anyways. But off-hand I don't recall a source for that.

Comment: As per the Medrash,  Haman arrived long before it was acceptable to be seen in the palace: וְנָדְדָה שְׁנַת הַמֶּלֶךְ אֲחַשְׁוֵרוֹשׁ, שֶׁרָאָה בַּחֲלוֹמוֹ אֶת הָמָן שֶׁנָּטַל סַיָּף לְהָרְגוֹ, וְנִבְהַל וְהֵקִיץ מִשְׁנָתוֹ, וְאָמַר לְסוֹפְרָיו הָבִיאוּ סֵפֶר הַזִּכְרוֹנוֹת לִקְרוֹת וְלִרְאוֹת מַה שֶּׁעָבַר עָלָיו, וּפָתְחוּ הַסְּפָרִים וּמָצְאוּ אֶת הַדָּבָר שֶׁהִגִּיד מָרְדֳּכַי עַל בִּגְתָנָא וָתֶרֶשׁ, וְכֵיוָן שֶׁאָמְרוּ לַמֶּלֶךְ: הִנֵּה הָמָן עוֹמֵד בֶּחָצֵר, אָמַר הַמֶּלֶךְ אֱמֶת הַדָּבָר שֶׁרָאִיתִי בַּחֲלוֹמִי, לֹא בָּא זֶה בְּשָׁעָה זוֹ אֶלָּא לְהָרְגֵנִי

Comment: I have no argument with the midrash, I was only offering a new understanding that might explain Haman's actions. I was not aware of the Midrash and so I stand corrected. However, I still believe that on the Pshat level my answer is plausible.

Comment: The Midrash does not say the king  saw Haman right after the dream. Apparently Haman came very early in the morning, and then Achashverosh connected it to his dream from earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect wicked Haman simply wanted to be early to the court to be first to address the king when he arose - his feet running swift to mischief.  Note though, Haman single-handedly violated five of the six things the LORD hates as revealed by King Solomon in Proverbs 6 (see below).  It was God's intervention that kept him from successfully "shedding innocent blood".  It is no wonder God leveled a powerful stroke of irony to seal his demise - being hung on his own gallows.

> [Proverbs 6:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.6.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) These six things doth the Lord hate: yea, seven are an abomination
>    unto him:
>
> [17](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.6.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) A proud look, a lying tongue, and hands that shed innocent blood
>
> [18](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.6.18?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) An heart that deviseth wicked imaginations, feet that be swift in running to mischief
>
> [19](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.6.19?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) A false witness that speaketh lies, and he that soweth discord among brethren.

Enemies of the children of Israel today would be wise to note:

> [Isaiah 54:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.54.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) No weapon that is formed against thee shall prosper; and
>   every tongue that shall rise against thee in judgment thou shalt
>   condemn. This is the heritage of the servants of the Lord, and their
>   righteousness is of me, saith the Lord.